# How implament fieldMask in python grpc updating request?

Tags: python, google-api, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have not understood completely how protobuf FieldMask works in grpc request, I've created this message from client, but I do not know how to receive and show the values in the server site.

`Client.py`

```
    fm = FieldMask(
        paths=[ 'f.a',
                'f2.a'
        ])

    msg = proto_pb2.Message(
            f=proto_pb2.F(a=a_value),
            f2=proto_pb2.F2(a=a_value)
    )

    new_message = proto_pb2.Message()
    fm.MergeMessage(msg, new_message)

    # Create message to send server
    request = server_manager_pb2.UpdateMessageRequest(
              id=proto_pb2.Message(id=message_id),
              update_mask=fm)

    # make the call
    response = stub.UpdateMessage(request)
```

but in `server.py`

```
    def UpdateMessage(self, request, context):
        print(request.update_mask)
```

is displaying the follow value:

```
    paths: "f.a"
    paths: "f2.a"
```

how can I display the field values sent by client in this server method or how FieldMask works?

Comment: I'm not sure that your question has anything to do with gRPC; I think it might be an entirely Protocol Buffers concern. In your service-side code you print the request object, but have you also tried printing the request object on the invocation-side? If so, the same thing is printed because the values are the same, right? If the values seem to be different: show us more of your code? What is `FieldMask` and from where does it get imported? What is `proto_pb2` and from where does it get imported?